# Replace in unicode python

Tags: python

I am trying to remove stop words from a unicode string. I use this code:

```
file = open("stop-word-list.txt", "r")
for line in file:
    text = text.replace(line, "")
file.close
```

Each line in the file is a stop word. "text" is the unicode. This only finds and removes one match it finds, not any others. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Example of part of the unicode:

```
 "It's not every day that an undergraduate student has the 
 opportunity to take a course offered in collaboration with Harvard Law School. 
 Starting in January, that is precisely the opportunity that will be available to 
 a number of Muhlenberg College students"
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example of your data also?

Comment: Can you please supply a some of the data, and an example of is the expected output and the actual output?

Comment: You probably want to use `line.strip()`

Comment: @pvg just put a thumbs up on your comment. But why does it find any match at all? It does not explain that. Tested the code with added strip and it's working fine in Python2+3

Comment: @pvg That worked perfectly, thank you so much!

Comment: @mkiever it's because the line provided by the iterator contains a newline. if the text you're testing against contains a match with a newline, that will be matched and replaced.